# was not declared in this scope in myfile

Tags: c++, csv, compiler-errors

hey so i wrote a code opening data in csv format in c++ and it shows me a error was not declared in this scope myFile.open

code :

````
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open (SBIN.csv);
    while (myFile.good()) {
        string line;
        getline(myFile, line, ',');
        cout<< line<<endl;
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: You haven't defined what `SBIN.csv` is. Maybe that's why.

Comment: i have file named this in the same folder

Comment: Then it should be myFile.open ("SBIN.csv")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
myFile.open (SBIN.csv);
```

with

```
myFile.open ("SBIN.csv");
```

`open()` accepts strings and you haven't declared a variable named `SBIN` or `csv`.